# Flash Player Unresponsive on Remoting Error - AS2

Tags: coldfusion, actionscript-2, remoting, flash

We have an application that was developed with Flash, AS2 and ColdFusion backend (remoting). I observed that when there was a database query failure, and that came in to Flash, the _result handler will be called (instead of _status), and the player hangs with the infamous unresponsive / abort the script error.

Doing a trace on the result produces nothing. Trying to enumerate properties in the result also produces nothing.

That's very strange. Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing this / how to solve it?

Comment: Try using Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/, or some other proxy that can read AMF) to look at the server response.  Also, have you tried stepping through with a debugger?  What version of flash player have you tested this in?

Answer (score 0):

Use debug version of flash player in your browser if you don't use it already, most likely it will throw an exception popup.

Second thing is to install http://amfexplorer.riaforge.org/ and see what back-end sends, if anything.

If this doesn't help try putting result parsing code into try-catch and see where it blows up applciation:

```
try {
   // statements
} catch (myErr) {
   // statements
} finally { 
   // statements 
}
```